# integral with summation and exponential

Tags: integration, summation, exponential-function

Could anyone help me how am I supposed to take the integral, while both the exponential and the outer terms have summation?

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{L}  \frac{1}{(e^{\frac{y}{s_k}}-1){s_k} } e^{-(\sum_{n=1}^{M} \frac{ry+r-1}{h_n})} dy $

I believe I should be able to approximate the result in some ways.

Comment: You should be able to move the outer summation outside of the integral and then for the inner one I would to see if there's a change of variables that would eliminate it.  I looks like a good part of that summation is constant WRT the variable of integration so you can pull that outside of the integration as well if that helps.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome thanks.  In $e^{-(\sum_{n=1}^{M} \frac{ry+r-1}{h_n})}$ part, I still end up with a summation on the exponent ; $e^{-(\sum_{n=1}^{M} \frac{r-1}{h_n})}e^{-(\sum_{n=1}^{M} \frac{ry}{h_n})}$, which  I do not know how to take the integral wrt $y$ in that case.

Comment: Looking at the form of the integrand, does it even exist?  You end up with a zero in the denominator at the lower bound with nothing I see that compensates.  See this form I think I reduced you inergral to (leaving out the outer summation): [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-b*x%5D%2F%28%28Exp%5Bx%2Fa%5D-1%29*a%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D)

Comment: Letting $b = \sum_{n=1}^M\frac r{h_n}$, pulling out the constant factor, and using the Taylor expansion of $e^t$, the integrand may be expressed as , $$\sum_{k=1}^L \dfrac{1-by + O(y^2)}{y + O(y^2)} = \frac Ly - Lb + O(y)$$whose integral will diverge at $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks. I did not get how you wrote the last expression, which diverges at 0.  What happened to $e^{\frac{y}{s_k}}-1$ ?

Comment: I used the Taylor series expansion of $e^t = 1 + t + \frac {t^2} + \dots$. Set $t= \frac y{s_k}$, and you end up with $\left(\frac y{s_k} + O(y^2)\right)s_k = y + O(y^2)$ in the denominator.